# Comparing some sentences with the participle

Tags: passive-voice, prepositional-phrases, ellipsis, participles

Could you explain to me the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> 1) Asked whether the discussion had brought agreement nearer, he said that every useful conversation was a step forward.
>
> 2) **Being** asked whether the discussion had brought agreement nearer, he said that every useful conversation was a step forward.

Does 1 mean that he was asked only once while 2 means that he was asked repetitively? 
Do you agree that "Asked whether the discussion ..." = "When asked whether the discussion ..."

> 3) Written in pencil, the article was difficult to read.
>
> 4) **Being** written in pencil, the article was difficult to read.

If I can make a conclusion about "one-off action versus a series of actions" in the first two examples then I can't see how a letter can be written by means of series of actions. What's the difference between 3 and 4?

Answer (score 4):

In your question, sentence **1)** is the right construction.

Yes "Asked whether the discussion ..." = "When asked whether the discussion ..."

In the case of sentence **2)** I would advice against using 'being', starting the sentence with 'being' is not wrong but it is lousy. 'Being' is used to denote a [state](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/being). It can also be used to start a sentence when the sentence is in [passive voice](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html) and the passive verb is the subject of the sentence, for example : being chased by a dog, he jumped over the high fence.

Sentence **2)** does not necessarily mean that he was asked repetitively , please do not confuse the usage of the word 'being' as used to denote repetition. As I mentioned above 'being' denotes a state, like human being - (novice translation) human state , it does not imply any repetition.

About the difference between **3)** and **4)** , they are both correct, it is similar to the example I provided above, but removing 'Being' from sentence **4)** does not make the slightest difference in the meaning. Again, please do not associate the meaning of 'Being' with 'A series of actions' or 'repetition' rather, 'Being' denotes a 'state' let me give you a few examples (pardon me if you could find the same examples elsewhere on the internet. No [plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) intended) :-

- Being Indian,I have to get a visa for every country I decide to visit.
- Being Blind, I am happy I don't have to see the horrors of the world.

In all the above sentences 'being' indicates state, it does not mean a series of actions or repetition.

> If I can make a conclusion about "one-off action versus a series of actions" in the first two examples

The conclusion you have to make is not about "one-off action vs series of action ", as long as it concerns the use of 'being' your conclusion should be about "Active and Passive voices".

I found a very interesting and similar discussion [in this forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2617225) I am certain it will help you understand when not to use 'being'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One thing to point out. In these sentences Being stressed always... Being a novice does... you use the gerund not the participle. So they can't illustrate the intended point. But I like the rest of your answer.

Comment: Got it, will edit it out, I am a non-native speaker of english, so I know stuff from practice but I am not always very accurate when it comes to grammatical terms, either way I will edit it out, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: In *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, both *-ing* forms are considered the same thing.  They call it the **gerund-participle**.  So at least some linguists consider the distinction unimportant (although you are free to continue making the distinction, if you like).

Comment: 1) Reading is great. - gerund 2) I saw him reading - participle. They are not the same no matter what someone says (in this case)